# Camera rotation around one axis of the scene TrackBallControls.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouse

I am using r59 of the three.js lib. Based on the stl loader example i am trying to rotate the camera around one axis of the scene. I use TrackBallControls to interface my scene with the mouse. 
When i move the mouse i want the scene to rotate with the objects around the origin z-axis. But i can't manage to find a way to block the others directions. Is it in the trackball or in the three lib ?

[image: Screen]

For example rotate arround the green axis but keeping the angle of the angle of the camera.
When i do :

```
var mouseOnBall = new THREE.Vector3(
        ( clientX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.left ) / (_this.screen.width*.5),
        0.0,
        0.0
    );
```

The camera rotates only around the green axis but it's not really straight as you can see on the screenshot. And i would like to keep the camera on the initial angle. See the second screenshot :

[image: Screen 2]

I am unable to find the anwser most of them on the internet are deprecated.

Sincerely
Austriker

Comment: Did you try `THREE.OrbitControls()` instead? You can constrain `maxPolarAngle` and `minPolarAngle`.